# NSTimer vs SKAction (performance)

Tags: ios, performance, nstimer, skaction

I am a bit new to the SpriteKit and Game development 
My question is what is better to use an SKAction like:

```
SKAction * shelvesAction = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(makeShelves) onTarget:self];
SKAction * delayAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
SKAction * runShelvesForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[delayAction,shelvesAction]]];
[self runAction:runShelvesForever withKey:@"shelvesAction"];
```

Or just an NSTimer

```
_shevesTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(makeShelves) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Which one is faster and what are the differences ?

Comment: Just use SKAction unless you have a reason to use something else with Spritekit

Comment: Could uou explain a bit more please ?

Comment: SKAction is quite performant and written by the SpriteKit team. In all likelihood it wraps NSTimer or something lower level. You probably won't see any improvement using something else but the key is don't try to optimize until you know you need to.

Comment: @uchuugaka Oh, I have a lag in my game when I am using adMob, and I used timers previously then I made a change to SKAction and didn't see difference so I asked here. Still want to optimise as much things as I can,do you know any good resource that I can read in order to make my code more efficient ?

Comment: @uchuugaka Also my question came to life in 1 more aspect well maybe I made the action wrong, but there is 3 SKActions I made in order to cover 1 timer, so i wasn't sure about if it is any better or not. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Nice example. I think the only thing you can do is run performance tests and compare. Instruments will help. Basically though it's likely that some actions may be optimized differently under the hood but no way to know. All you can do is measure and test.

Comment: I guess to test it I should make a tiny project aside with implementation of 2 of those and then test :)